# User Security in Access / Excel - Retrieve Domain / Machine Name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I was using environ("username"), then moved to:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function fOSUserName() As String
' Returns the network login name
Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
Dim strUserName As String
strUserName = String$(254, 0)
lngLen = 255
lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
If (lngX > 0) Then
    fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
Else
    fOSUserName = vbNullString
End If
End Function
```

But I want to be able to check what the domain is, and if it is an actual domain or just a local machine name etc... Is this possible?

I've already had discussions regarding setting up domain groups/security groups etc, so do not need input regarding these thank you.

Comment: Do you mean something on these lines http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2010/12/16/vba-how-to-get-the-account-login-user-name-and-the-account-full-name-for-a-program-ex-microsoft-word.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

well, `Environ("USERDOMAIN")` should get the domain name, but if you want to use api declarations, then you would need:

```
Private Declare Function LookupAccountName Lib "advapi32" Alias "LookupAccountNameA" (ByVal lpSystemName As String, _
    ByVal lpAccountName As String, Sid As Byte, cbSid As Long, ByVal DomainName As String, _
    cbDomainName As Long, peUse As Long) As Long
```

an example can be found [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19685)

Comment: `Environ()` is not a good match with "User Security".  An evildoer can simply open a command prompt, mung environment variables, and start the Access application from there.  "Security" which relies on `Environ()` is not real security.

Comment: @HansUp, I agree. using Environ is a low level of security, but you should match effort against desired level. If all I want is a log of who used my application, then Environ is OK. if I need to assign access rights, then I'm going to use a different level of security, and match against domains and groups

Comment: You're conflating 2 separate albeit related issues: user logging; and security.  In the absence of *genuine* security, I could do this: `C:\Users\hans>set USERNAME="sean.chesire"` Then if your logging relies on `Environ("USERNAME")`, I could masquerade as you.  :-)